# What role does a public certificate play in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, coldfusion

We have our own certificate that we use as part of the `ClientCredentials` in Transport Client Credentials as seen below.

```
WSHttpBinding wsBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
wsBinding.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.SecurityMode.Transport;
wsBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
wsClient = new WSService.WSClient(wsBinding, new EndpointAddress(serviceURL));
wsClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, clientCertificateSubjectName);
```

Our partner also provided us with a copy of their certificate that is used on the server in order to validate their server. Calls to the service currently succeed without us having installed or done anything with this certificate.

We are using ColdFusion and generally we have to install these into the java certificate store - but its odd to me that service communication is working under Visual Studio when I have not done anything with the service's certificate

What is the role/purpose of the service certificate? Do clients install it in the MMC Certificate Trusted People in or reference it in the client-side configuration e.g. WSHttpBinding above?

Comment: What do you mean by "their public certificate"? Is this the server certificate of this web service which has a publicly valid chain of trust. Or is it the client certificate where they accidentally gave you only the certificate without the private key? Or what is the purpose of this certificate you mention there? Anyway, your web service client is configured correctly as long as this server accepts your self signed client certififacte.

Comment: @Anateus the service provider gave us a certificate file. This is the server certificate of the endpoint and I am assuming I should be using it to validate the server?

I just wasn't sure if I needed to install that certificate in MMC in order for the client to be able to verify the server/correctly communicate. Was just looking for clarification.

Comment: @Anateus Updated the question to provide more clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to communicate with the server through SSL, both the client and the server needs to accept each others certificate, if the server is configured to require a client certificate. Since you already succeeded to communicate with the server this means that:

- the server accepted your client certificate or was not configured to require a client certificate
- your client explicitly accepts the server certificate or does it implicitly because this certificate has a valid chain of trust on your client (the issuing CA or root CA is in your trusted root CA list and the certificate is not contained in any revocation list)

If you want to allow only the communication with a server which sends the certificate that your partner provided to you. Then you need to write code, so that your client explicitly compares the server certificate with this certificate and then goes on with your calls to the service or let it kill the connection.

To answer your question: The only purpose, I can think of, of this explicitly provided certificate is that it is used in the scenario which I described above.

Comment: I see - we are also integrating with ColdFusion which uses java to communicate and I think the server cert needs to be in the java certificate stores in order to communicate with the server otherwise the connection is killed by the client-side java web service clients. Your response was helpful - Really appreciate it